# Jenkins-github repository error (windows)

Tags: github, jenkins

I am using github with jenkins.
I was able to successfully clone the github repository but when I add the URL of repository in Jenkins, I am getting following error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub ls-remote -h git@github.com:username/game-of-life.git HEAD
```

The URL is: git@github.com:username/game-of-life.git

I have added the path of github in jenkins main configuration, which is:

> C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub

I have tried other solutions such as generating ssh keys for github and jenkins.

Any idea about this error?
Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you do a "git clone" of that repository from the command line?

Comment: @CLGuy: The problem has been solved. In Jenkins system configuration, I was giving wrong path. I had to use %GIT_HOME%\bin\git.exe or %GIT_HOME%\cmd\gitk.cmd. In my case gitk.cmd is working.

Comment: @CLGuy: regarding your question: it clone that repository into github successfully, without any error message.

Comment: Glad to hear your problem was solved. You should post your solution as an answer so that others can find it.

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins system configuration, add the path of git.exe file.
In my case, git.exe in

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_some#\bin\git.exe

did not work but "gitk.cmd" in ...cmd\gitk.cmd worked fine.