# Jenkins don't see Git repositorium on Mac

Tags: git, jenkins

I want to give Jenkins local path to my Git repository. I initiated in that folder git repo with `git init` command, but when I set a path in Jenkins config page I get :

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h 

/Users/asd/Documents/workspace/mavenTest HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: '/Users/asd/Documents/workspace/mavenTest' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the correct path of git installation directory under "manager jenkins". In my case I had the same problem in windows and I configured the path of installation directory to:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_randomnumber\cmd\gitk.cmd

already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196681/jenkins-github-repository-error-windows) for windows.